# Selenium Webdriver, Javascript link, Unable to locale Element

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver

Hi I am facing this issue, Below is a code which i had generated using Selenium IDE, Basically i am trying to access a career portal of the particular website below and for the Jobposting QA specialist, I was experimenting to auto complete the application using Selenium.

1) I am not able to replicate the code working in webdriver despite adding the code under proper class and importing all the necessary packages.
2) On running it as a TestNG test, i have a failure showing Unable to find Element.
3) The link to the QA specialist is not being detected by the driver either if i give it as identify By.link text or By.xpath.
4) please guide me where i am making mistake.
5) I am a beginer to Selenium

```
  public class Application {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.saymedia.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testApplication() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/jobs");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("QA Specialist")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apply Now")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send Application")).click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are inside of an `iframe`.  Selenium only interacts with elements in the current frame.  Any element within a child `frame` cannot be interacted with until you switch into that `frame`.  You can switch by using `switchTo().frame()`:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/jobs");
driver.switchTo().frame("jobviteframe");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("QA Specialist")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apply Now")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send Application")).click();
```

The arguments for `frame()` are

- number from 0
- id of the `frame`
- the `webelement` rerference of the `frame`

When done in the `iframe`, use the following to exit back to the top of the document:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Hello Richard Thanks for your Help, i rectified the above situation sucessfully, But there is another such situation with a particular website www.mate1.com; 1) On clicking the login link a form box opens up on the same page, on analyzing the no of frames in that particular page i found it as 7, despite switching in to each frames seperately and searching for the email field by the xpath or the id; selenium doesnt recognize them and throws me the Unable to find the element error, can you help me out.

Comment: @user3705385 Probably best addressed in a new question, I think?

Comment: Sure will post it new